# DRF CamelCase parser not working on actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my project, i have added the [Django REST Framework JSON CamelCase package](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case) according to the documentation.
I'd like to implement a method like this one:

```py
@action(detail=False, methods=['patch'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated])
def something(self, request):
    body = json.loads(request.body)
    print(body)
    o = self.get_queryset().get(pk=body['id'])
    s = Serializer(o, data=body)
    if s.is_valid():
        s.save()
    return Response()
```

However, this method prints the variables I sent in camelCase, not in snake_case, so the object can't save. What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I'd still like an answer as to why the above didn't work.**

I've found a workaround by just using the parser directly in the method. Instead of using `body = json.loads(request.body)`, I use `body = CamelCaseJSONParser().parse(request.stream)`.